# Integrating functions to return an array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import math as m
#import quadpy

#The function
I = lambda l: 0.06977 + (7.0625*(1-m.exp(-((l-0.26053)/0.15994)))**2.28411)*(m.exp(-((l-0.26053)/0.15994)))
np.vectorize(I)

def Iint(z):
    return integrate.quad(I, 0, z)

Iint=np.vectorize(Iint)
z=np.arange(0,100)

Ia=Iint(z)
print (Ia)
```

It leaves the error "Can't convert complex to float"

Thanks in advance 
Please help me out with this

I think the error arises from the function not being vectorised

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):`

  `File "C:\Users\Admin\.spyder-py3\untitled2.py", line 22, in <module>
    an=Iint(z)`

  `File "D:\Jupyter\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)`

  `File "D:\Jupyter\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2161, in _vectorize_call
    ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)`

  `File "D:\Jupyter\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2121, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
    outputs = func(*inputs)`

  `File "C:\Users\Admin\.spyder-py3\untitled2.py", line 17, in Iint
    return integrate.quad(I, 0, z)`

  `File "D:\Jupyter\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 342, in quad
    points)`

  `File "D:\Jupyter\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 453, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)`
```

Comment: Can you please include the entire traceback of the error?

Comment: Please format it as code. The edit window has good instructions. You should read them carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `np.vectorize` - it is slow and hard to use right.

```
 # Iint=np.vectorize(Iint)
 z=np.arange(0,100)
 alist = []
 for i in z:
      alist.append(Iint(i))
 print(alist)
 print(np.array(alist))
```

the bare:

```
 np.vectorize(I)
```

does nothing.  It does not operate in-place.

The error ,"Can't convert complex to float" may be the result of the trial `otypes` the `np.vectorize` does.  It the first call to `quad` returns a real value, it expects all calls to do that.  I suspect that for some `z` larger than 0, the result is complex.  So you could get around this error by setting `otypes`, but I still think `np.vectorize` is inferior.